# is it possible that Android loads a fresh instance of previously opened Activity instead of loading some in memory instance?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have Activities **A, B & C**.

**A** loads **B** and **C**.

***BEFORE UPDATE***

i load **B** from **A** ... than i pressed back button and A was loaded... i again loaded **B**.

Now is it possible that some previous instance of B is loaded instead of creating a new fresh instance of **B**.. as i am having some weird issues??

i want **A** to always load a FRESH instance of **B** .. but dont know how...

***AFTER UPDATE***

I studied the Intent filters and found the following having same concept... so i applied Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to force android to always load a fresh copy of **B**

```
// THIS CODE IS IN ACTIVITY A -- TO LOAD ACTIVITY B
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(A.this, B.class);
//Trying to force it to load a fresh instance of B      
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```

**Now** It loads B, i suppose a fresh copy.. but when i press BACK button, it closes the App instead of showing main activity **A** which loaded **B**.. I think above flags causes activity **A** to close after loading activity **B**.. i m not sure

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: i think you need this FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the press of the hardware Back button will remove the Activity from the current task. Every time you make A launches B, B press Back, A is displayed, you launch B again, B **will** be a **fresh** instance, unless you overwrite the Back button to put the Activity at the end of your stack (this is not what you want and is not so by default).  You can check that by either putting a log in the onCreate of B, or using the debugger and putting a breakpoint in the onCreate - if your code goes through onCreate - it is a **fresh** instance.
With the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK you're removing A from your history and the press of the back button from B will exit your application.

I think the weird issues are not caused by a loading of old copy of B.

Comment: thanks for the explanation ... i will try to figure out what causes that situation ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use those flags for this task. You are basically separating **B** from **A** entirely. In a normal situation you get a stack like

**Home** -> **A** -> **B**

Using those flags you get two stacks

**Home** -> **A**

**Home** -> **B**

Your desired "new instance of B" is the default behavior based on what you described. Like Glatzial says, if you put a log in the onCreate of **B** you will see that its created every time you go to **B** from **A**.

Comment: My resent experience showed that FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK doesn't automatically put B in a new task. You have to set a specific android:taskAffinity in the manifest for that activity. Only then it'll go in a new task. So in this case, if taskAffinity is left empty by default you will get Home -> A -> B

Comment: That's odd. The documentation (when talking about affinities) says: 
"Some entities (such as the notification manager) always start activities in an external task, never as part of their own,...."

Comment: I was surprised myself. Here is my test scenario. Activity A is singleTop and called with flag combination new_task, clear_top, single_top. Activity B is called from A with a simple Intent. Activity C also singleTop, is called from a background thread with the same combination as A. I expected to have two tasks. T1: A -> B and T2: C. But if you call A again (same flags) both B and C are killed ( due to clear top). So in reality it was only one task with A -> B -> C. If you define an affinity for C it works as expected - if A is called only B is killed and C is not visible but not destroyed.